# Creating RPM for 3rd party software with local site configuration

Tags: rpm

I download and create RPM packages for 3rd party software. There is a ./config directory that contains various config files that are specific to my company but are not part of the software bundle downloaded from the vendor. Previously, I have just manually copied my company specific ./config/files* across to the destination server after the RPM has been installed but I'm searching for a more elegant way of doing this programatically.

How can this be achieved within the SPEC file?

Comment: What research have you done? The documentation on `rpmbuild` seems to be fairly clear on the `Source*` directive and how to use a the shell command `install` in the `%install` section of the spec file.

Comment: You can probably create a rpm called yoursoftware-config or something similar, which is having the official one as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a separate `thirdpartysoftware-config-yourcompany` RPM package that contains only the config files and depends on the main RPM package via `Requires: thirdpartysoftware`, versioned as appropriate.

This could also be a subpackage of the main package (a `%package` section in the SPEC file), but that creates unnecessary churn because a new subpackage gets built whenever the main package is updated, which would make little sense if the config remains unchanged.